How to get the selected/clicked leaf node of Fluent UI V9 Tree component
I am using Fluent UI V9 Tree control (https://react.fluentui.dev/?path=/docs/components-tree--docs). When I am clicking the branch node, It is calling the onOpenChange event where i am getting the selected node. But when I am clicking the leaf node, onOpenChange is not getting called. I think this was working earlier. Does anybody know how can i get the selected leaf node?
I tried using onClick event but it gets called on branch and leaf node selection and I am not getting the selected node.
